# NSURL returns null while sending JSON service request?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, request, nsurl

My url is `http://sample_domain/sample.json?{ "language" : "en", "category" : "sports"}`

I am converting this to NSURL object like below.

```
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://sample_domain/sample.json?{ "language" : "en", "category" : "sports"}"];
```

its returning nil to NSURL object, i know the URL should be in specific format from apple documentation,otherwise it will be considered as a malware site and returns nil object,

my question is how can i pass these paremeters with apple standards, so that it will not retun nil object.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you encode the data differently? It might make more sense to use normal query encoding, e.g.: `http://sample_domain/sample.json?language=en&category=sports` As you can see, it's still the same information but now it's working much more with the way the normal web works instead of insisting on doing it differently.

Comment: Hi Donald,if i try this even in browser i am not getting response, but if i do like below NSString *str1=[@"\"lan\" : \"en\", \"cat\" : \"menus\" " stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
 NSString *str2=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://domain/test.json?{%@}",str1];
 NSURL *sample=[NSURL URLWithString:str2]; now i am getting nil url object, but if i copy and paste the 'str2' in browser i am getting response data, so here i should not encode '{' aswell NSURL should not be null, any ideas please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:[@"http://sample_domain/sample.json?{ \"language\" : \"en\", \"category\" : \"sports\"}"
                  stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

I'm not sure why '"' characters are not escaped in your example, but I think without escapes your code should not compile.

Also you need (and that's the main problem) to replace characters that are illegal in url (e.g. ':' with corresponding percent escapes - that's what stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding function does.

Comment: Hi Donal i tried using the stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding, now i am getting the url, but the response data from the URL is Zero bytes, if i copy paste the url to the browser same issue, then i noticed this method encoding the '{' to '%7B' is this a problem.

Comment: @mac if url is correct the problem you don't get result may be in your server - try to look into it

Comment: my problem here is i should not encode '{','}',in my url string, in my browser itself if i encode braces and send request i am not getting response, so my question is, how do i get valid NSURL object which contains '{','}', please give me some ideas.

Comment: Thanks for the solutions @Vladimir,@Donal i have removed the '{,}' in my URL and just encoded my url string, now i am getting data, as well url.